# Can I set up a different method of authentication on Nagios?

Tags: authentication, nagios

Nagios is a wonderful too for monitoring servers. Their web interface is not bad, either. However I am not crazy about using the HTTP Authentication that comes standard.

**Is there a way to use another method of authentication?** (and I don't mean restricting access by IP address in the .htaccess file) Something with a form-based login would be wonderful, but perhaps there is no such thing. I'm hoping you guys have found something I haven't.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but maybe you would like to have a look at [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org) which started as a Nagios fork. It has (among other things) a pretty AJAX-based web UI and an extended CGI interface.

Comment: interesting. are you a developer for them? i thought nagios was sort of industry standard and also open source - what are the big advantages of icinga?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_auth_form.html

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is can I change the way the authentication is enforced - using a PHP session instead of basic authentication or something like that - not the actual verification of credentials. I've accepted the current answer though as it is accurate - just like the honeybadger, nagios doesn't care how you protect the webpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nagios doesn't care how you have the webserver handle the authentication. Nagios simply takes the authenticated user passed from the webserver to compare against the configuration. You could also disable authentication within Nagios itself and handle authentication in the webserver directly. Doing this would either allow all authenticated users the same access level or would require separate configurations to restrict/limit access to Nagios features.

Here's the link to the [Nagios 3.0 CGI Auth](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/cgiauth.html) documentation.

Comment: Disabling authentication at the nagios level will break the ability for anyone to issue commands via the web interface, iirc.

Comment: You then have to enable the default user in the nagios config and update the config to allow that user to issue commands via the web UI. You can then configure the web server to handle the authentication in whatever manner you wish separate from Nagios but you won't be able to have separate access levels within Nagios.

Answer (score 2):

Nagios doesn't do its own authentication, as others have mentioned; it relies on httpd to pass the authentication through.

Therefore, you can use any of the dozens of auth modules for apache's httpd, including many that use form-based logins (WebAuth, CAS, OpenID, probably SAML, etc.). These are only practical if you already have some sort of SSO available where you are. If not, authing to a directory service (AD, LDAP) or a database might be more practical.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use forms based authentication but I have found that [mod_auth_radius](http://freeradius.org/mod_auth_radius/) from the FreeRadius project works well in my environment to provide single sign on.

You could also look into direct LDAP authentication if you have something in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up on this post, as I have.

I have got nginx using oauth2-proxy to auth to my keycloak server and hand the email on to nagios, nagios will use the email as the username.

`fastcgi_param    REMOTE_USER $email;` is the magic in nginx.